# При импорте инфоблока копируются не все элементы в Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Пытаюсь перенести инфоблок на другой сайт путем экспорта-импорта.

При экспорте вижу есть все элементы в файле .xml, однако при импорте на другом сайте загружаются разделы, но элементы большей частью отсутствуют.

Пытался и через .csv, все-равно не получается. Копировать руками очень много работы.

Подскажите, это глюк или я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: Скорее всего глюк. Стоит обратиться в поддержку и приложить к обращению файлы используемые для импорта.

Comment: Главное проверил, элементы загрузились в БД, но почему-то не отображаются...

Comment: тогда точно надо писать в саппорт. это уже явно проблемы в движке

Comment: решили проблему?

Comment: @Oleksandr нет, не решил

Comment: тогда если не сложно можете дать ваш xml файл?
не обязательно со всеми товарами(если у вас там какая-то комм. тайна), хочу потестить на чистой машине, если там все ок пойдет, тогда уже проблема конкретно на вашей стороне, а если нет, будем смотреть. Желательно с товарами, которые у вас отсутствуют.